# Trying to access the value from a nested array

Tags: arrays, twig

I'm currently working with `woocommerce` using `timber` plugin that provides a twig template engine. Right now I'm trying to access a value that is within a nested array `["sizes"]`. How do I fetch the value `400ml` from inside the `"[sizes]"` array.

```
["_product_attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["sizes"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Sizes"
        ["value"]=>
        string(5) "400ml"
        ["position"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["is_visible"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["is_variation"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["is_taxonomy"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["color"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Color"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "Red"
        ["position"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["is_visible"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["is_variation"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["is_taxonomy"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
```

I tried the snippet below but it only returns empty

```
     {% for attr in post._product_attributes.sizes.value %}
       
     
       {{ attr }}
    
      {% endfor %}
```

The snippet below returns `NULL`

```
     {% for attr in post._product_attributes.sizes %}
       
       <pre>
       {{ dump(attr.value) }}
       </pre>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Usually, per an old convention variables staring with an underscore are private members of a class. So most likely, that is your issue here, you cannot access it because the property `_product_attributes` is private. This said, you maybe have a getter like `post.productAttributes`.

Comment: From what I see in [their docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_attributes) I am guessing (*untested*): `post.get_attributes().sizes.value` would do the trick.